# Cursor always returns empty (while it shouldn't)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to read from SQLite database and the method I am using to get Cursor always returns an empty Cursor.

This is the method:

```
public Cursor getUrls(int oddelki){
    String[] columns = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.RAZRED, SQLiteHelper.URNIK_URL};
    String selection = SQLiteHelper.RAZRED+"=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{oddelki+"%"};
    open();
    return db.query(
            SQLiteHelper.IME_TABELE2,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null, null, null);
}
```

In the column "RAZRED", data is saved in this format: 1.A, 1.B, 1.C, 2.A, 2.B etc. so when I read from database, I want all data that has "RAZRED" which starts with 1. That is why I am using the % (oddelki+"%").

Here is how I then use the method to read data:

```
Cursor c = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext()).getUrls(1);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            Log.i("TAG", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.RAZRED)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

But cursor never moves to first row. The IF condition always fails. There **is** data in the database that starts with 1. I've checked multiple times, I'm sure of it. The cursor shouldn't return empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the column "RAZRED", data is saved in this format: 1.A, 1.B, 1.C, 2.A, 2.B etc. so when I read from database, I want all data that has "RAZRED" which starts with 1. That is why I am using the % (oddelki+"%").

Then use the `LIKE` operator and not `=` equality. Change

```
String selection = SQLiteHelper.RAZRED+"=?";
```

to

```
String selection = SQLiteHelper.RAZRED+" LIKE ?";
```

Comment: Ohhh, yes!! I'm out of practice with SQL these days, I haven't worked with it in such a long time that I completely forgot about "LIKE". Thanks a lot!